# Running Twitter Bootstrap modal box with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need a bit of help in Twitter Bootstrap modal.
For example:
I have a button:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
```

and I need a to launch a modal via jquery script. So i found in tutorial that that script line will do the job:

```
$('#myModal').modal(options)
```

But that script line in `<script></script>` tags not working and in Bootstrap tutorials is written that it should.
Any ideas?

So it is on open cart 2.x shop and it is fully working with the modal it self called method without script

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <h1>This is a text</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so that modal is fully opening with this line:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">The test modal box</button>
```

but I need the same modal div open with jquery script instead of `data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"` this method.
Because i need to run modal open after the product is putted to the shopping cart and then is used this script in another jquery script which opens modal.
In the Twitter Bootstrap instructions it is written that

```
<script>
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
</script>
```

does the job, but it is not opening anything. So, any ideas?

Comment: show us your full code? and what error are you getting

Comment: Did you loaded Jquery also? Show is your scripts that you load

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id` attribute to your modal and can use jQuery code to show the modal. Example below.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#lauchModal").on('click', function () {
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
  $("#lauchModalAnother").on('click', function () {
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h1>This is a text</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<button id="lauchModal" type="button">Launch modal</button>
<button id="lauchModalAnother" type="button">Launch modal Another</button>
```

Comment: It works above in my code. The modal will be closed when you click outside the modal or press `Escape` key.

Comment: ok, i did it, but can you tell me why on the two same buttons added ,modal on one is working and on another, not?

Comment: You can refer to my updated answer above. It works. Click on each button and click outside modal, then click on second button, the modal is displayed again. Hope this helps.

Comment: if i copy and paste your buttons for example two or three times, first button opens modal window and rest of buttons not, but the are the same and id is the same too, what can it  be wrong ?

Comment: Id's should be different for all elements in HTML.

Comment: But i need to run the same modal on each button (it opens a modal with buttons either i want to go to checkout or continue shopping), so if i generate on each button different id how it would work on script? also i should make a new generated #lauchmodal name on the script and on the each button ?